# Number of unique sequences of 3 digits (-1,0,1) given a length that matches a sum

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-algorithm

Say you have a vertical game board of length n (being the number of spaces). And you have a three-sided die that has the options: go forward one, stay and go back one. If you go below or above the number of board game spaces it is an invalid game. The only valid move once you reach the end of the board is "stay". Given an exact number of die rolls t, is it possible to algorithmically work out the number of unique dice rolls that result in a winning game?

So far I've tried producing a list of every possible combination of (-1,0,1) for the given number of die rolls and sorting through the list to see if any add up to the length of the board and also meet all the requirements for being a valid game.  But this is impractical for dice rolls above 20.

For example:
t=1, n=2; Output=1
t=3, n=2; Output=3

Comment: If the only valid move once you reach the end of the board is "stay" then how can you go above or below the board?

Comment: If you could give some examples for `n` and `t` (as well as the expected answer), it would be helpful to validate if my implementation is correct :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  t=1, n=2; Output=1.  t=3, n=2; Output=3

Comment: My answer gives the correct answer for those cases, but you have to validate it further. If that answers your question, please do not refrain from marking it as correct :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dynamic programming approach. The sketch of a recurrence is:

```
M(0, 1) = 1
M(t, n) = T(t-1, n-1) + T(t-1, n) + T(t-1, n+1)
```

Of course you have to consider the border cases (like going off the board or not allowing to exit the end of the board, but it's easy to code that).

Here's some Python code:

```py
def solve(N, T):
    M, M2 = [0]*N, [0]*N

    M[0] = 1
    for i in xrange(T):
        M, M2 = M2, M
        for j in xrange(N):
            M[j] = (j>0 and M2[j-1]) + M2[j] + (j+1<N-1 and M2[j+1])

    return M[N-1]

print solve(3, 2) #1
print solve(2, 1) #1
print solve(2, 3) #3
print solve(5, 20) #19535230
```

**Bonus: fancy "one-liner" with list compreehension and reduce**

```py
def solve(N, T):
    return reduce(
        lambda M, _: [(j>0 and M[j-1]) + M[j] + (j<N-2 and M[j+1]) for j in xrange(N)], 
        xrange(T), [1]+[0]*N)[-1]
```

Comment: Would using generators rather than iterations help reduce the amount of memory consumed in a case like this?

Comment: I really don't think so. The code is already optimized to only keep the last two lines of the DP, so it's space complexity is O(N). I don't think there is room for more improvement. I tried a version with generators, just to be fancy, but this DP construction with loops is very traditional and I think any other implementation technique would sacrifice readability.

Comment: Would you mind posting the version with generators?  I'm really curious if mine is on par.  Also thanks for being so responsive and helpful!

Comment: @Andrew Actually, it wasn't a generator, it was a list comprehension. The idea is the same as the version above, but less "comprehensible" :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, after further research I totally agree that a generator wouldn't decrease the amount of memory utilized.  Thanks for the help

Comment: That is on seriously beautiful one-liner.  This is why I love python.

Comment: @Andrew and Juan, Since I'm not too much of an expert, I'm not sure if my answer might offer a slight optimization (perhaps with more optimized binomial coefficients?) but thanks for a fun question and the opportunity to learn more.

Comment: @JuanLopes I don't understand what M[] and M2[] represent, nor why you do M, M2 = M2, M at the start of ever outer loop. Could you please explain that?

Comment: @Greg This is a bottom-up dynamic programming. But we only need the last value of the last line of the table. And to build each line we only need the previous line. So, instead of keeping the entire table in memory, we only keep the current line (`M`) and the previous (`M2`). `M, M2 = M2, M` just swaps the lines, setting the current as previous and making room for a new line.

Comment: @JuanLopes How exactly did you come up with the recurrence formula? I tried to come up the formula by hand but I was not able to.

Answer (score 4):

Let `M[i, j]` be an `N` by `N` matrix with `M[i, j] = 1` if `|i-j| <= 1` and `0` otherwise (and the special case for the "stay" rule of `M[N, N-1] = 0`)

This matrix counts paths of length `1` from position `i` to position `j`.

To find paths of length `t`, simply raise `M` to the `t`'th power. This can be performed efficiently by linear algebra packages.

The solution can be read off: `M^t[1, N]`.

For example, computing paths of length 20 on a board of size 5 in an interactive Python session:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> M = numpy.matrix('1 1 0 0 0;1 1 1 0 0; 0 1 1 1 0; 0 0 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0 1')
>>> M
matrix([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> M ** 20
matrix([[31628466, 51170460, 51163695, 31617520, 19535230],
        [51170460, 82792161, 82787980, 51163695, 31617520],
        [51163695, 82787980, 82792161, 51170460, 31628465],
        [31617520, 51163695, 51170460, 31628466, 19552940],
        [       0,        0,        0,        0,        1]])
```

So there's `M^20[1, 5]`, or 19535230 paths of length 20 from start to finish on a board of size 5.

Comment: An ingenious solution, but a little expensive, I think. Considering optimum algorithms for the task, it would be O(n^2.4 * log(t)). Still upvoting though :-)

Comment: Oh, there's one problem: this solution doesn't consider you can't leave the last space once you reach it.

Comment: @JuanLopes it does consider that you can't leave the last space once you reach it.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. And used your result to validate my own implementation. They match. :)

Comment: @JuanLopes you can stay in `numpy` and cut expenses by using `numpy.poly(M)` and recursing on the negated coefficients (save for the first).

Answer (score 0):

Try a backtracking algorithm. Recursively "dive down" into depth `t` and only continue with dice values that could still result in a valid state. Propably by passing a "remaining budget" around.

For example, `n=10, t=20`, when you reached depth 10 of 20 and your budget is still 10 (= steps forward and backwards seemed to cancelled), the next recursion steps until depth `t` would discontinue the `0` and `-1` possibilities, because they could not result in a valid state at the end.

A backtracking algorithms for this case is still very heavy (exponential), but better than first blowing up a bubble with all possibilities and then filtering.

Comment: This isn't a greedy algorithm. And greedy algorithms aren't always "heavy". On the contrary, most of them have very low complexities, as they by definition choose the local maximum (or minimum) instead of searching for all global maxima.

Comment: Sorry, I meant backtracking. Of course this isn't a greedy algorithm. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Since zeros can be added anywhere, we'll multiply those possibilities by the different arrangements of (-1)'s:

```
X (space 1) X (space 2) X (space 3) X (space 4) X
```

(-1)'s can only appear in spaces 1,2 or 3, not in space 4. I got [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256843/how-many-arrangements-of-s-selections-from-r-possibilities-have-at-least-one) with the mathematical recurrence that counts the number of ways to place minus ones without skipping backwards.

JavaScript code:

```js
function C(n,k){if(k==0||n==k)return 1;var p=n;for(var i=2;i<=k;i++)p*=(n+1-i)/i;return p}

function sumCoefficients(arr,cs){
  var s = 0, i = -1;
  while (arr[++i]){
    s += cs[i] * arr[i];
  }
  return s;
}

function f(n,t){
  var numMinusOnes = (t - (n-1)) >> 1
      result = C(t,n-1),
      numPlaces = n - 2,
      cs = [];

  for (var i=1; numPlaces-i>=i-1; i++){
    cs.push(-Math.pow(-1,i) * C(numPlaces + 1 - i,i));
  }

  var As = new Array(cs.length),
      An;

  As[0] = 1;

  for (var m=1; m<=numMinusOnes; m++){
    var zeros = t - (n-1) - 2*m;
    An = sumCoefficients(As,cs);
    As.unshift(An);
    As.pop();
    result += An * C(zeros + 2*m + n-1,zeros);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Output:

```
console.log(f(5,20))
19535230
```

Comment: There are 21 possibilities with three -1s and you've only counted 17. They are +++-+-+-++ +++-+--+++ +++--++-++ +++--+-+++ +++---++++ ++-++-+-++ ++-++--+++ ++-+-++-++ ++-+-+-+++ ++-+--++++ ++--+++-++ ++--++-+++ ++--+-++++ +-+++-+-++ +-+++--+++ +-++-++-++ +-++-+-+++ +-++--++++ +-+-+++-++ +-+-++-+++ +-+-+-++++