# foobar challenge: Minion's bored game

Tags: java, algorithm

---

**Edit:** It appears people are confusing this question for [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837067/number-of-unique-sequences-of-3-digits-1-0-1-given-a-length-that-matches-a-su). Both questions are about the same Foobar challenge. The other question asked for an approach better than the exponential time or omega(answer) brute force search, since a brute force search took too long. The answers there suggested using dynamic programming, which is a good idea that is much faster than a brute force search or backtracking, although not the best possible. This question **starts** with dynamic programming, which works on 4 out of 5 tests, but which seems to get the wrong answer for the 5th and perhaps largest test case. It doesn't take too long. It completes but gets the wrong answer. The answers to the other question do not help with this question, nor does the answer to this question help with that one, so they are not duplicates. They are about different aspects of the same task.

---

I am working on a Foobar Challenge, trying to determine the number of possible "Winning" roll combinations an individual could make using a 3-sided die. The simulated user will roll t times on a 1-dimensional "game-board" that is n spaces wide. The 3 sided die has 3 possible values: left (-1), stay (0), right (1). User starts out at location '0' on the board. If you are at 0 and you roll a -1 (left) then the game is invalid. If you are on the final square the only valid roll is 0 (stay). The objective is to determine the total amount of roll combinations a user could make that ends up with their marker being on the last square. (READ THE FULL CHALLENGE DESCRIPTION BELOW).

I have a semi-functioning solution to this challenge; however, when I submit it for review it fails 1 out of 5 test scenarios; problem is, Foobar doesn't disclose what the exact scenario was that failed, it simply says 'Test 5 failed!'. Would anybody be able to look at my Java code (below) and see what I am missing?

Here is my code:

```
public static int answer(int t, int n) { 
if ((n - t) > 1) {
    return 0;
}
if (n == 2) {
    return t * 1;
}
if (t == n) {
    return n;
}
// Use dynamic programming:
int lst[] = new int[n]; // lst[k] holds the # valid paths to position k using i-1 steps
int lst2[] = new int[n]; // put # valid paths to position k using i steps into lst2[k]
int total = 0;
lst[0] = 1;
lst[1] = 1;
int max = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < t; i++) {
    lst2 = new int[n];
    if (max < (n - 1)) {
        max++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n && j < (max + 1); j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            lst2[j] = lst[j] + lst[j + 1];
        } else if (j == max) {
            if (j == (n - 1)) {
                total += lst[j - 1];
            } else {
                lst2[j] = lst[j - 1];
            }
        } else {
            lst2[j] = lst[j - 1] + lst[j] + lst[j + 1];
        }
    }
    lst = lst2;
}
return total % 123454321;
}
```

### Original Challenge Text

There you have it. Yet another pointless "bored" game created by the bored minions of Professor Boolean.

The game is a single player game, played on a board with n squares in a horizontal row. The minion places a token on the left-most square and rolls a special three-sided die.

If the die rolls a "Left", the minion moves the token to a square one space to the left of where it is currently. If there is no square to the left, the game is invalid, and you start again.

If the die rolls a "Stay", the token stays where it is.

If the die rolls a "Right", the minion moves the token to a square, one space to the right of where it is currently. If there is no square to the right, the game is invalid and you start again.

The aim is to roll the dice exactly t times, and be at the rightmost square on the last roll. If you land on the rightmost square before t rolls are done then the only valid dice roll is to roll a "Stay". If you roll anything else, the game is invalid (i.e., you cannot move left or right from the rightmost square).

To make it more interesting, the minions have leaderboards (one for each n,t pair) where each minion submits the game he just played: the sequence of dice rolls. If some minion has already submitted the exact same sequence, they cannot submit a new entry, so the entries in the leader-board correspond to unique games playable.

Since the minions refresh the leaderboards frequently on their mobile devices, as an infiltrating hacker, you are interested in knowing the maximum possible size a leaderboard can have.

Write a function answer(t, n), which given the number of dice rolls t, and the number of squares in the board n, returns the possible number of unique games modulo 123454321. i.e. if the total number is S, then return the remainder upon dividing S by 123454321, the remainder should be an integer between 0 and 123454320 (inclusive).

n and t will be positive integers, no more than 1000. n will be at least 2.

Languages
To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py To provide a Java solution, edit solution.java

Test cases

Inputs: (int) t = 1 (int) n = 2 Output: (int) 1

Inputs: (int) t = 3 (int) n = 2 Output: (int) 3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Qiang Zheng. This question may be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but we'll see if we can't help you out.

Comment: @Addison Broken code is off-topic on Code Review. There is some leeway for unexpected corner cases, but the author of the code would have the burden of demonstrating why he / she thinks the solution is correct.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: It doesn't look like a duplicate to me. The task is the same, but the question about the task is quite different.

Comment: @DouglasZare Yes, I agree "possible dupe" is the wrong close reason, but I stand by my vote to close. I think that "this code doesn't work" questions need to be a specific problem with debugging the code rather than "please fix the bugs in my code". Answering the latter question doesn't really help anyone. PS. I'm glad you're active on the site... I'm a fan of your backgammon writing!

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: Paul Hankin agreed that this is not a duplicate, and I think he deleted his comment saying that it is a duplicate. Please justify your closure of this problem as a duplicate. Both questions involve the same Foobar Challenge but they ask different things, and the answers to each question do not answer the other question.

Comment: @Qiang Zheng What did you change to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counts grow exponentially in t. My guess is that the error is that you are overflowing the integer range. Reduce intermediate results mod m, or use a [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Sorry, but I have the exact same problem. I'm on the final problem, and I want to know what you did solve it. What do you mean by 't'? What did you change to fix it? I'm quite confused and am Only fourteen and really want to complete it. Please help.

Comment: @PythonandAndroidforlife: The variable t is defined in the problem description. It is the number of rolls it must take to move across the board. Do you understand what overflowing the integer range means?

Comment: Yes, I think. Keep in mind I'm young. But, I believe it is that integer is a little over 2 billions units. When it overflows the range, it goes over the amount of units a integer can hold, 2 billion. So using a BigInteger would fix the problem because it can hold as many units as a long. But t is never added to in the code, so I'm confused. It should not go over 2 billion units. :( please explain.

Comment: @PythonandAndroidforlife: Suppose someone asks for the last digit of the 1000th Fibonacci number. Those are 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,... with f[n+1]=f[n]+f[n-1]. One thousand doesn't overflow the integers, but f[1000] does. It has 209 decimal digits. So, two approaches that work are to use BigIntegers to compute the Fibonacci numbers and to reduce all of the intermediate calculations mod 10, since you only need to keep track of the last digits of f[n] and f[n-1] to compute the last digit of f[n+1]. This is very similar to what happens in the current problem. The count overflows, not t.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!!! :) One last question could I simply use a `long` value instead, and return a `(int)` encased value of the `long` 'total'? Like so:
`long total = 0;
total += t[1000];
return (int) total;`

Comment: Actually here is a better representation of what I'd like to do:
`long[] listOne = new long[numberOfSquares];
long[] listTwo = new long[numOfSquares]
long total = 0;
total += listOne[1000] + listOne[100 -1] + listOne[1000 + 1];
long answer = total % 123454321;
return (int) answer;`
Sorry for a decent amount of code in comment. Just what to show you what I mean. :/

Comment: Wait so what exactly am I creating as the BigInteger also? the two lists? or the total?

Comment: Longs might not be large enough. Instead of long[], you can use BigInteger[]. You should be aware of the other approach, though. BigIntegers can get slow.

Comment: This code gives a null pointer exception when converted to BigInteger[]. It cannot call .add() with certain elements of the list.

Comment: Wait no never mind I just realized I have to initialize every element in the list to make it a non primitive type BigInteger. What is the other approach again? XD

Comment: Reduce intermediate results mod m. It's like keeping just the last digits of the intermediate Fibonacci numbers if you only need the last digit of f[1000].

Answer (score 0):

Ok to make it simple yes there is a problem with int overflow. However you don't need to use a larger container ex BigInteger. All you need to store int the second array is the remainder ex `lst2[j] = (lst[j - 1] + lst[j] + lst[j + 1]) % 123454321;`. By doing this your value will never exceed 123454321 which will easily fit within an integer. then after every iteration of i use `total %= 123454321;` then you just need to return total. Since we are just adding paths moding the intermediate result just reduces it back to a manageable number.